# Pasar query de Mysql a MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente query en Mysql 8.0, al pasarla a MariaDB 10.6 no funciona, hay error de sintaxis. Es un update con CTE. Las query de tipo SELECT con CTE sí son compatibles.

```
WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            t.id as id,
            t.identificador as identificador,
            IFNULL(t.valor_cuota_individual, 0)*1048576 as cuota_asignada
            FROM proxy_usuario t INNER JOIN grupo_de_navegacion g ON t.grupo_id = g.id where g.chequear_consumo_de_cuota = 1
    )
    UPDATE proxy_usuario T1
INNER JOIN cte ON T1.id = cte.id
SET
T1.consumo_actual =
    (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as consumo
        FROM access_log_internet internet
        WHERE internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683640804 AND 1683644040
        AND internet.http_reply_size > 0
        AND internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403')
        AND internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE')
        AND internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE')
        GROUP BY internet.http_username
        HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador
    ),
T1.overcuote = (
SELECT IF(cte.cuota_asignada < (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(internet.http_reply_size), 0) as consumo
            FROM access_log_internet internet
            WHERE (internet.time_since_epoch BETWEEN 1683640804 AND 1683644040)
            AND (internet.http_reply_size > 0)
            AND (internet.http_status_code NOT IN ('407', '403'))
            AND (internet.squid_request_status NOT IN('TCP_DENIED', 'TCP_HIT', 'TCP_MEM_HIT', 'TCP_IMS_HIT', 'TCP_INM_HIT', 'NONE', 'NONE_NONE'))
            AND (internet.squid_hier_status NOT IN('HIER_NONE'))
            GROUP BY internet.http_username
            HAVING internet.http_username = cte.identificador
    ), 1, 0)
)
```

**ACTUALIZANDO**: Este es el error que muestra el phpmyadmin al correr la query en MariaDB

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'UPDATE proxy_usuario T1 INNER JOIN cte ON T1.id = cte.id SET T1.consumo_ac...' en la linea
> 9

El este es el DER resumido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Y el resultado que se espera:** A todos los usuarios que pertenecen a grupos de navegación a los que se le controla la cuota de acceso a internet, calcularle el consumo actual basado en los registros de navegación almacenados en la tabla `access_log_internet` (tabla MyISAM no relacionada) y con columna en común `proxy_usuario.identificador = access_log_internet.http_username`, tomando de dicha tabla los registros que cumplen con las condiciones especificadas en la query para el intervalo de tiempo indicado por las marcas de tiempo (Acotar aquí que se pudiera en vez de pasar por parámetro el intervalo de tiempo, pues que el SGBD calcule el espacio transcurrido entre la hora entera actual y la hora con minutos actual, digamos para la hora y minutos en curso 9:36A.M el cálculo se realizaría con los registros entre las 9:00A.M y las 9:36A.M). En el caso que ese valor de consumo calculado sobrepase el valor de la cuota asignada al usuario expresada en MB, poner la columna overcuote a 1.

Comment: Te faltó incluir el error que te da al usar el código

Comment: @Alfabravo lo siento, ya actualicé la pregunta con el error.

Comment: Las CTE funcionan con UPDATE en MySQL, pero al parecer no están soportadas en MariaDB, como está [reportado](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-update-with-a-recursive-query-not-working-error-1241/) y [lamentado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65317742/woes-using-update-with-a-cte-in-mysql-mariadb). Probablemente necesitarás encontrar una solución alternativa extrayendo la actualización o UPDATE de la CTE. Si nos proporcionas las tablas y más código, podríamos ayudarte.

Comment: @alejandroMAD inicialmente hacia el procesamiento desde la aplicación, dividiendo la tarea de actualización en partes. Para ganar en rendimiento es que me salto el ORM E intento pasarle el trabajo al SGBD, pero desafortunadamente como me explicas es lo que está sucediendo. En un rato les cuelgo las tablas.